# Laravel eloquent - Many to Many, select only matching the many table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 3 tables describing users, roles and role_user. These look like this:

```
users -> id, name
roles -> id, name
role_user -> user_id, role_id
```

In my User class I have:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
}
```

The aim here is of course to allow a user to have multiple roles.

I can do a query like `User::with('roles')->get()` which works fine.

What I want though is only to select users that have a certain role, ideally specified by name, but it could be by ID instead if needed. How do I do this using Eloquent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write a `belongsToMany` relationship in `Role` Model

```
    class Role extends Eloquent {
        public function users() {
            $this->belongsToMany('Users');
        }
    }
```

Then use Following Eloquent Query.

```
    $role = Role::with('users')->whereName($name)->first();
```

You can access all users that have `$name` role as `$role->users`.

Comment: That's completely the opposite of what I was trying – obvious when you know how!

Comment: Indeed - On a Many To Many, it is confusing as the function "belongsToMany" actually is used applies when you want to say "hasMany" --  "hasMany", however, is already used when doing a 1 to many relationship. So you end up using "belongsToMany" when it's more like "ownedByMany"...or something.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by [tharumax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133477/tharumax) is completely valid and extremely useful. The only problem is if you want to run the query with other things. Let's say, the users that have an `admin` role and signed up before 2014. Or if you want to use it as a scope, you can't do it his way.

This is another way but directly on the query (though this one searches by id):

```
User::join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
      ->where('role_user.role_id',$id)->get();
```

If you want, you could create a scope for easier syntax and management. e.g I want to get the users with role `admin`.

Scope:

```
// Inside User model

public function scopeAdmins($query)
{
  return $query->join('rol_user', 'users.id', '=', 'rol_user.user_id')
               ->where('rol_user.rol_id', id_of_admin );
}
```

Then you could easily retrieve all the `admin` users doing this (and add other conditions if you need to):

```
User::admins()->get();
```